# Disable Browser Downloaded File Execution

Tags: chmod, executable

How can it be possible to ensure that downloaded files through web browser (location pre-set), are not able to be executed by default?

Comment: Please show us an example of the file(s) that caused you to ask this question. Because: .... 
Most installable files for Ubuntu are in packages with a .deb extension. When downloading a pop-up windows appears asking you what to do with the file; store it or open it with Software Installer. Other downloads, like .tar(.gz) cannot execute anyway. They have a separate install procedure (in Terminal: unzip, untar, run script). Others are .bundle (VMware uses it) that is also a script which must be started in a terminal.

Comment: It would be just general install scripts such as a bash script

Comment: Executing by a browser of downloaded files is a customizable setting in the browser. For ex: in Firefox -> Preferences -> Applications some default definitions are pre-set. As long as a file has an extension (.sh, .ksh, ...) you can force the browser to Ask what action to take after downloading. If a file has no extension, just its name, the browser doesn't know what to do. A different matter is control by the website via cookies, etc. In that case you must take appropriate action in the browser. The greater message here:  read before you download.

Comment: Ahh thanks. I may have to adjust the question. Basically the downloaded location should not allow execution access, shell, it less about the browser. - Compliance Problem

Comment: The Download Location (any directory) is not relevant. Its the permissions of the downloaded file as soon as its written (umask). If the file has x-bits set, it can be executed by just entering its name in a terminal. However, to execute a file WITHOUT x-bits, simple give the command `sh file` and it will get started. So you see its more complex than you may think. I did find a good suggest in an old post, you may want to have a look at:

Comment: Old link: "You probably want to go to security.stackexchange.com - what you're asking about is how to secure a system from physical attack. Lots of this will have been covered there already - but read their FAQ (security.stackexchange.com/faq) first. – Cry Havok Apr 1 '13 at 17:44"